# Add validations on dynamically created form with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a form dynamically with javascript. Now I have to add validations on the form (only mandatory validations) on click of the button which is also dynamically created. Now the issue I am facing is that whenever I try to add addEventListener on the button exactly after creating it, it is giving me error.
        (
        function init() {

```
    console.log("div created"); 

    // create a new div element
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "registration_form";

    var createForm = document.createElement("form");
    newDiv.appendChild(createForm);

    var heading = document.createElement("h2");
    heading.innerHTML = "Registration Form";
    createForm.appendChild(heading);

    var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
    createForm.appendChild(linebreak);

    createElement(createForm, 'label','','','Name: ');
    createElement(createForm, 'text', 'dname', '','');
    createSpanTag(createForm,'nameError');
    breakTag(createForm);breakTag(createForm);
    createElement(createForm, 'label','','','Email: ');
    createElement(createForm, 'email', 'email', '','');
    createSpanTag(createForm,'emailError');
    createElement(createForm, 'button','Validate','Validate','');
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',validate());
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newDiv);

}
)();

function createElement(formElement,type,name,value, placeholder) {
if(type=='label'){
    var element=document.createElement(type);
    if(name!='' && value!=''){
        element.setAttribute('name',name);
        element.setAttribute('value',value);
    }
    element.innerHTML=placeholder;
    formElement.appendChild(element);
} else {
    var element=document.createElement('input');
    if(type!=''){
        element.setAttribute('type',type);
    }
    if(name!=''){
        element.setAttribute('name',name);
    }
    if(value!=''){
        element.setAttribute('value',value);
    }
    if(placeholder!=''){
        element.setAttribute('placeholder',placeholder);        
    }
    formElement.appendChild(element);
} 

}

function breakTag(createForm){
createForm.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}

function validate(){

}
function createSpanTag(createForm, id){
    var element=document.createElement('span');
    element.setAttribute('id',id);
    createForm.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Provide some code and what did you try so far.

Comment: @MarkoSavic can you please suggest now?

Comment: Please mention the `line` where you are getting error, and also add error message.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of addEventListener needs to be a function. 
Change ...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',validate())
```

to ...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',validate);
```

Comment: Doing this, I got the following error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Since your tag name is `input`, not `button`. So use `input` in parameter of the function `getElementsByTagName()` and then loop through all nodes and find node with `type` = `button`.

Try change this line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click',validate());
```

to:

```
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
    {
       if (nodeList[i].getAttribute("type") == "button") {
       {
          nodeList[i].addEventListener('click',validate);
       }
    }
```

Comment: I got following error: Uncaught TypeError: nodeList[item].getAttribute is not a function

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. I simply did this and still no output:
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
   if (nodeList[i].getAttribute("type") == "button") {
    nodeList[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
     alert('hi');
    });
   }
  }

Comment: If i am not wrong, the issue is most likely related to DOM not being ready and we are trying to apply the events.

Comment: What exactly the scenario, not working can have different meanings, are you getting any error message, or simply click event is not getting fired? check your console, may be possible if it is giving some error?

Comment: I now used the following and it is not working fine:
var items = createForm.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (var i = items.length; i--;) {
   if(items[i].getAttribute('type')=='button'){
    items[i].addEventListener('click',validate);
   }
  }